# Pandas MySQL exception don't shows

Tags: mysql, pandas, ssh, jupyter-notebook

I have this code for connect to MySQL through a SSH, inside of a python class:

```
def executeQuery(self, query_string):
        print("connecting to database " + self.sql_main_database)
        with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (
            self.ssh_host,
            self.ssh_port),
        ssh_username = self.ssh_user,
        ssh_pkey     = self.pkey,
        remote_bind_address=(self.sql_hostname, self.sql_port)
        ) as tunnel:
            print("performing connection")
            conn = pymysql.connect(
            host="127.0.0.1",
            user=self.sql_username,
            password=self.sql_password,
            db=self.sql_main_database,
            port=tunnel.local_bind_port)
            query = query_string
            print("Querying")
            data = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
            print("Done!")
            conn.close()
            return data
```

The code is working well, but when the query is not well defined, the notebook freezes.

Then, I tried to use a try/catch, and the code ended like this

```
def executeQuery(self, query_string):
        try:
            with SSHTunnelForwarder(
                (
                    self.ssh_host,
                    self.ssh_port
                ),
                ssh_username = self.ssh_user,
                ssh_pkey     = self.pkey,
                remote_bind_address=(self.sql_hostname, self.sql_port)
                ) as tunnel:
                try:
                    conn  = pymysql.connect(
                        host  = "127.0.0.1",
                        user  = self.sql_username,
                        password = self.sql_password,
                        db    = self.sql_main_database,
                        port  = tunnel.local_bind_port
                    )
                    try:
                        query = query_string
                        data = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
                        return data
                    except DatabaseError as e:
                        Log.debug(self,str(e))
                        raise DatabaseError
                except pymysql.err.InternalError as e:
                    Log.debug(self, str(e))
                    raise DataError
        except Exception as e:
            Log.debug(self, "[Error]Setting up database: \'" + self.sql_main_database + "\'")
            raise DataError
```

The issue is that pd.read_sql_query never stops so the except is never called, the try won't fail, and the process will just continue forever

The timeout workaround is not possible, because the queries don't have defined execution times and some of them can stay in processing during a couple of hours.

I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: You could use a timeout with PyMySQL: https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/connections.html

Comment: The timeout workaround is not possible, because the queries don't have defined execution times and some of them can stay in processing during a couple of hours.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed the problem was not on the connector, just updating the jupyter version was needed.